# How to add value to !this.value?

Tags: javascript, html, keyup

How can I add value to this so it only allows numeric input?

```
function validatemycode() {
    $('datagroup').on('keyup', 'input[id^="datagroup_1"]', function () {
        if (!this.value){
            alert('Alert Message Here.');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Using RegEx, for example

Answer (score 1):

A Regex-free edition:

```
function validatemycode() {
    $('datagroup').on('blur', 'input[id^="datagroup_1"]', function () {
        if (!isValidInput(this.value)) {
            alert('Alert message here.');
        }
    });
}

function isValidInput(value) {
    var allowedCharacters = '0123456789'.split('');
    return string.split('').every(function (char) {
        return allowedCharacters.includes(char);
    });
}
```

What happens in `isValidInput` is:
1. We make an array out of `0123456789` (=`['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']`).

2. We make an array out of the input (same as in the previous step).
3. `every` returns `true` if **all** of the elements of the array passes the test, which is: is the current character (of the original string) is included in the `allowedCharacters` array. If there's a character that is not a number, we return `false`.

This is also a nice exercise in functional programming.

Note: this won't work on Internet Explorer (since `includes` is not supported there).

Comment: Is there a way to do this and instead of an alert message, the action of them pressing the key is prevented. (e.g. preventDefault())

Comment: And also, is there a regex free way to do this so it works in IE?

Comment: @Stormy, the problem is that you're listening to the `blur` event, which fires when you lose focus of the input element, so I am not sure how you can prevent from typing... You can, however, listen to the `keydown`/`keyup` event(s) and `preventDefault()` if the key that was just pressed is not a number.
Personally, I don't like this approach as it seems confusing to the user, and it sounds to me like a not-so-good user experience.

Comment: @Stormy, about IE support - I believe you can find a polyfill to `includes`. Honestly, this function is not so sophisticated by itself so you can even implement it yourself pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Regexp/test) , that returns true or false.

```js
var a = "abcABC";
var b = 1321321;
var c = "21321abc";
var d = "132 1321 ";


//only numbers
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/g.test(a))
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/g.test(b))
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/g.test(c))
console.log(/^[0-9]+$/g.test(d))
```

in your code:

```
function validatemycode() {
    $('datagroup').on('blur', 'input[id^="datagroup_1"]', function () {
        if (/^[0-9]+$/g.test(this.value)){
            alert('Alert message here.');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: How does this "only allow numbers?" What happens if there are characters that are not numbers, but also are not in the `[a-zA-Z]` class, such as `*` or `%`?

Comment: I doesn't really answer the question then.

Comment: Sorry, it's still broken. This doesn't test for only numbers: `/[0-9]/g.test(a)` it only tests that there is a number. For example, it returns true for `abc123`

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, you are right. My point was that .test is a good way, in my opinion, to put into an if statement because it returns true or false. I didn't take to much attention to the regex. I've updated the answer again

Comment: Is there a way to also prevent the user from entering a space character as well?

Comment: @Stormy sure, `^[0-9]+$` prevents spaces. I've added the example.

Comment: I've tried adding this to my code, however it is still allowing spaces

Comment: @Stormy keep in mind if you have `/^[0-9 ]+$/` instead of `/^[0-9]+$/` the regex will allow spaces.  You have to remove all spaces in `[0-9 ]`

Comment: I didn't have any spaces, I wrote it as /^[0-9]+$/ and it was still allowing spaces

Comment: @Stormy I've tested the code in chrome, Firefox and node and doesn't allow spaces, maybe the problem is not here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` to check if there's any char that is not a number `[^0-9]`

```js
$('.datagroup').on('blur', function () {
    if (!this.value || this.value.match(new RegExp("[^0-9]", "g"))){
        console.log('Not Ok');
    }else{
        console.log("Ok")
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="datagroup"/>
```

Comment: Apologies, I needed it to work as the answer from Emeeus below has it functioning. I cannot add the additional script you included.

Comment: Which additional script? It's the same code you have, just added a `input` to use as example and the check (`match()`) with `RegExp`, that is the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method to check whether or not the string contains something other than numbers. See below:

```
var containsLettersOrCharacters = function(value) {

    var split = value.split('');

    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

        if(isNaN(Number(split[i]))) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Here we're breaking the string into individual characters using `split()`, then looping through each one and checking whether the value of `Number(character)` is `NaN`. If `isNaN()` returns true here, that means that the character isn't a number.

The important thing here is that Number() against a string other than a number in string format will result in a NaN value.

Can use this as such:

```
if(containsLettersOrCharacters(value)) {
    //the string contained something other than numbers
}
```

Hope this helps.